# Not able to change v-dialog style

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I want to change the margin on the .v-dialog class and the max-height when it's not full screen.

The code from the console:

```
.v-dialog {
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin: 24px; <-------- want to change this
  overflow-y: auto;
  pointer-events: auto;
  -webkit-transition: .3s cubic-bezier(.25,.8,.25,1);
  transition: .3s cubic-bezier(.25,.8,.25,1);
  width: 100%;
  z-index: inherit;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 11px 15px -7px rgba(0,0,0,.2), 0 24px 38px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.14), 0 9px 46px 8px rgba(0,0,0,.12);
  box-shadow: 0 11px 15px -7px rgba(0,0,0,.2), 0 24px 38px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.14), 0 9px 46px 8px rgba(0,
}
```

and:

```
.v-dialog:not(.v-dialog--fullscreen) {
  max-height: 90%; <--------- want to change this
}
```

It's not enough just to add a class to the v-dialog component somehow it dosen't register it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's always a good idea to use the docs for reference, if you haven't done so already.

https://dev.vuetifyjs.com/en/components/dialogs#dialogs

You have to use the `content-class` property, instead of the normal `class`, if you want to attach a class to the `v-dialog`

> Applies a custom class to the detached element. This is useful because
>   the content is moved to the beginning of the v-app component (unless
>   the attach prop is provided) and is not targettable by classes passed
>   directly on the component.

In this class you can then override the `margin` and `max-height`:

```
.custom-dialog.v-dialog{
    margin: 10px;
}

.custom-dialog.v-dialog:not(.v-dialog--fullscreen) {
  max-height: 50%;
}
```

Comment: I have added the content-class like: 

<v-dialog content-class="custom-dialog" color="#FAFAFA" v-model="showDialogForProduct" hide-overlay>

and the css you suggested but the style is not working?

Comment: @MaikenMadsen Can you see if it's applied in the developer console?

Comment: It is applied but the styling is not, thats so wiered?

Comment: Are you running the  `npm run serve` or `npm run dev`, so it actually compiles the styling? Or how are you actually writing the style?

Comment: I'm running it with npm run serve. The style is in the same .vue file. The styling in the file is working fine on the other elements?

Comment: In the developer console it looks like this: 

<div class="v-dialog custom-dialog v-dialog--active" style="">

So the costume-dialog class is applied.

Comment: It was because the styling was placed in scoped style, now it's working, but the answear was correct for the actual question :-)